# How to notify ListView that DataModel has changed

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, qtquick2, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-cascades

I created a `ListView` and I want to use it with a custom `DataModel`. However, I have a problem: at the moment the view gets created, I don't have the data loaded into the model. The model data is set after the view is created and when I set the data onto the model, the view doesn't update and doesn't read again the model data. This is my `ListView`:

*ListViewCountainer.qml*

```
Container {
    // countryModelData is set after ListViewCountainer gets created 
    // when countryModelData gets set, the model is populated with data
    property variant countryModelData

    leftPadding: 20.0
    rightPadding: 20.0
    topPadding: 20.0
    bottomPadding: 20.0

    CountryDetailsListView {
        id: countryDetailsListView

        dataModel: CountryDataModel {
            countryData: countryModelData
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my model:

*countrydatamodel.h*

```
#ifndef COUNTRYDATAMODEL_H_
#define COUNTRYDATAMODEL_H_

#include <QtCore/QAbstractListModel>
#include <QtCore/QList>
#include <QObject>
#include <QtCore/QVariant>

#include <bb/cascades/DataModel>
#include <bb/data/JsonDataAccess>

class CountryDataModel : public bb::cascades::DataModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant countryData READ getCountryData WRITE setCountryData)

public:
    CountryDataModel(QObject* parent = 0);
    virtual ~CountryDataModel();

    Q_INVOKABLE int childCount(const QVariantList& indexPath);
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant data(const QVariantList& indexPath);
    Q_INVOKABLE bool hasChildren(const QVariantList& indexPath);
    Q_INVOKABLE QString itemType(const QVariantList& indexPath);
    Q_INVOKABLE void removeItem(const QVariantList& indexPath);

    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant getCountryData();
    Q_INVOKABLE void setCountryData(QVariant data);

private:
    QVariantList m_elements;
};

#endif /* COUNTRYDATAMODEL_H_ */
```

*countrydatamodel.cpp*

```
#include <src/countrydatamodel.h>

#include <QtCore/QtAlgorithms>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>

#include <bb/cascades/DataModel>
#include <bb/data/JsonDataAccess>

CountryDataModel::CountryDataModel(QObject* parent) : bb::cascades::DataModel(parent)
{
}

CountryDataModel::~CountryDataModel()
{
}

bool CountryDataModel::hasChildren(const QVariantList &indexPath)
{
    qDebug() << "==== CountryDataModel::hasChildren" << indexPath;

    if ((indexPath.size() == 0))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int CountryDataModel::childCount(const QVariantList &indexPath)
{
    qDebug() << "==== CountryDataModel::childCount" << indexPath;

    if (indexPath.size() == 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "CountryDataModel::childCount" << m_elements.size();

        return m_elements.size();
    }

    qDebug() << "==== CountryDataModel::childCount" << 0;

    return 0;
}

QVariant CountryDataModel::data(const QVariantList &indexPath)
{
    qDebug() << "==== CountryDataModel::data" << indexPath;

    if (indexPath.size() == 1) {

        return m_elements.at(indexPath.at(0).toInt());
    }

    QVariant v;
    return v;
}

QString CountryDataModel::itemType(const QVariantList &indexPath)
{
    Q_UNUSED(indexPath);

    return "";
}

void CountryDataModel::removeItem(const QVariantList& indexPath)
{
    if(indexPath.size() == 1) {
        m_elements.removeAt(indexPath.at(0).toInt());
    }

    emit itemRemoved(indexPath);
}

QVariant CountryDataModel::getCountryData()
{
    return QVariant(m_elements);
}

void CountryDataModel::setCountryData(QVariant data)
{
    m_elements = data.toList();

    qDebug() << "================== CountryDataModel: " << m_elements;
}
```

I put some debug messages in the `childCount` function for example and it  gets called only once, which means that the `ListView` asks the model for the data just once, when the model is created.

Is it possible to force `ListView` to read again the data from the model after the model gets populated with data? Or how could I make this approach work and load the data in the view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order for the model to be updated, the `setCountryData` member function needs to be updated like so:

```
void CountryDataModel::setCountryData(QVariant data)
{
    m_elements = data.toList();

    emit itemsChanged(bb::cascades::DataModelChangeType::AddRemove, QSharedPointer< bb::cascades::DataModel::IndexMapper >(0));
}
```

FML...

Answer (score -2):

You need to declare a signal for the property you want to update in backend.

```
Q_PROPERTY(QVariant countryData READ getCountryData WRITE setCountryData NOTIFY contryDataChanged)
```

add its declaration as well.

Then you say -

```
emit contryDataChanged();
```

wherever you feel like list should re-read contents. (normally setter methods).

Comment: making countryData a property and emitting a notify signal doesn't have anything to do with the view.